# Export local contacts from iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, contacts, gmail

My primary means of handling contacts on my iPhone is gmail sync, but somehow it appears I have added a number of contacts to my phone locally. I want just these local contacts to sync back to gmail.

I'm fine with exporting and then importing to gmail, and then deleting the local contacts off my phone. However, I can't seem to find any good way of doing this.

Comment: Can you make use if a computer and iTunes to do a one time move? That is free and easy.

Comment: @bmike If you have a good way to do it, definitely throw an answer in. My Google Fu is weak on this one it seems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with [My Contacts Backup](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/my-contacts-backup/id446784593?mt=8). This will allow you to export all your local contacts as vCard which can be imported into Gmail.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Remove your Gmail account from your device (so that only the local contacts are backed up), then backup your contacts. You can then import the .vcf into your Gmail.

Comment: This worked for me, was free, and was pretty easy. CHOSEN.